# Power BI Max value per ID

Tags: powerbi, dax

How do I get the **MAX** value  of  **QUANTITY** per **PRODUCTID** in Power BI ? 
It really doesn't matter if the number keeps of repeating but its also better if you could help me create a new Table for this solution.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following calculated column can do:

```
MostOrder = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(Sales[Quantity]),
    FILTER(
        Sales,
        Sales[ProductID] = EARLIER(Sales[ProductID])
    )
)
```

`EARLIER` is a very useful function which allows you to compare a value to previous evaluation context.

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Did you really put all those inputs ? I am quite impressed on your effort for putting all those inputs. I am very new to this program.

Comment: @Shulz Thanks. Haha not really. I use a chrome plugin with OCR functionality to grab as much as possible of the dataset into Power BI. (Hence some errors) Then I modify some of the ProductID to show more results.

Comment: @FoxanNg Could you please share the name of the plugin? Inspired by your comment just tried CopyFish and Project Naptha but got garbage on the same image.

Comment: @user5226582 Yup the one I used is Copyfish. It returns around 90% correct for the image in this question, which is acceptable to me because I was merely trying and didn't expect it to return good results on numeric only image. It performs much better for normal word translation. Remember to set it to the correct language before using it. As for numeric results, I tried Chinese first and it sucks, then I switched it to English and it performs OK.